# How should I get "/actuator/health/readiness" to perform all custom metrics?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

It is well known that "/actuator/health" executes all HealthIndicator implementations, as long as you add the @component annotation. But if "/actuator/health" is used in livenessProbe and readinessProbe , it's not appropriate, according to the rule, if I want "/actuator/health/ readiness" to execute my custom HealthIndicator after the ReadinessStateHealthIndicator, what should I do? I'm very confused.

I want "/actuator/health/readiness" to execute a bunch of my custom HealthIndicators after it executes the ReadinessStateHealthIndicator.